# PL/SQL calling a cursor with a variable

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

i have 9 different cursor with different sql statements.

but the cursor for loops are always the same. is there any possibility to not to write 9 cursor for loops?

my idea was

a for loop to increase the cursorname stored in a variable

and the cursor for loop with the variable insteat of the cursorname.

but it doesn't work

thats my cursor for loop:

```
  FOR rec IN abgl2_cur LOOP
utl_file.putf(vFileHandle,
                '<s3>\n<%s> %s</%s>\n<%s>%s',
                c_grem,rec.gremium,c_grem,c_name,rec.name);
  utl_file.putf(vFileHandle,
                '</%s><%s>%s</%s>\n</s3>\n',
                c_name,c_id,rec.id,c_id);
  utl_file.fflush(vFileHandle);
END LOOP;
```

Comment: Move the common code into a procedure?

Comment: no it doesn't work, i write some variable from the cursor in a file. And it throws errors when i declare the sub-procedure because the cursor is not int the sub-procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to wrap the looping part into a procedure/function with parameter which would point on which cursor is need to be run. 
Then just call the procedure 9 times with different parameter.

If you want more specifics you should add some code here to work on.